# adding values to fields of a table repeatedly

Tags: mysql, text, addition, field

I am trying to insert text values to the field `img` of a table called `counterimg` in my database. Now, the table looks like this:

```
id  img
1   0.jpg
2   1.jpg
3   3.jpg
4   4.jpg
5   5.jpg
6   6.jpg
7   7.jpg
8   8.jpg
9   9.jpg
10  0.jpg
11  1.jpg
12  2.jpg
13  3.jpg
...
```

What I would like to do is to keep adding such that for every 10 values for example between id = 30 to 40, the img values should be 0.jpg to 9.jpg. This should continue till, id = 999.

How do I do that in MySQL or using MySQL query (in some sort of loop)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [modulo operation (`%`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). In your case, it would be modulo 10:

```
0 % 10 = 0
9 % 10 = 9
10 % 10 = 0
19 % 10 = 9
...
```

For example, a typical algorithm in your case could be:

```
for each i in [0 999] do
    id  <- i
    img <- (i % 10) + ".jpg"
    save (id, img)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain with some examples, how can I write a modulo operation inside a mysql query?

Comment: In your case, you have to use a `for` loop. You can either do it within a MySQL procedure, or with a third technology (PHP, JAVA, etc.). What are your needs?

Comment: If you go to the link: http://werecycle.engr.uga.edu/, you will find a counter called UGA SmartBin real time logging counter. What I want is to have the tables in a database with the corresponding image names, so that I can write queries to handle counter value from 000 to 999. How can I do that via PHP?

Comment: Man, have a look on the Internet. I gave you the solution, you just have to write a for loop in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

jus refer this and customize the query to your requirement.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,89453